# LibGDX BitmapFont drawing

Tags: fonts, bitmap, libgdx

So I'm creating an interface for game and I have an issue with the bitmap font I'm using *Distance Field Fonts* When font is increasing everything is fine but when it is decreasing font is getting so small that you can't even see it.

What I'm talking about:

Big screen
[image]

Small screen (320P)
[image]

Code:

Create:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("visuals/fonts/Arial.png"), true);
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, TextureFilter.Linear);

font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("visuals/fonts/Arial.fnt"), new TextureRegion(texture), false);
font.getData().setScale(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.0004f);
```

Draw:

```
batch.setShader(GameInterface.getDistanceFieldShader());
GameInterface.getDistanceFieldShader().setSmoothing(0);
font.draw(batch, text, getX() - textWidth / 2 + getWidth() / 2, getY() + textHeight + getHeight() / 5);
batch.setShader(null);
```

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Make sure you're using MipMapLinearLinear or MipMapLinearNearest for the `minFilter` of the font texture.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm using "TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, TextureFilter.Linear"

Comment: How are you constructing the font in the game? You also need to set mip mapping on in the Texture constructor

Comment: @Tenfour04 I updated the post, added some code, that is the only thing that I do in code with the font.

Comment: It may be that the letters are just too skinny to be drawn at such a small size with a distance field font. Not sure if it would help to generate your font at a larger size. Those letters look pixelated at the large size. Do you even need distance fieldas?